# Update custom package to upper version - HtmlAgilityPack Issue

Tags: package, html-agility-pack, umbraco8

I'm new to Umbraco package creation and I have updated the Umbraco 7 custom package to Umbraco 8, HtmlAgilityPack dll is packed within the folder and it is used while handling publishing events in code. But when I installed the package to Umbraco 8 website and published the created content it gives the following error.

*Server error: Contact administrator, see log for full details. Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.8.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

Anyone can help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 0):

Found that Umbraco 8 installation automatically installs HtmlAgilityPack as a dependency. So we don't need to install  HtmlAgilityPack separately through our package.
After removed HtmlAgilityPack from package content, issue solved